# How the ELF-VLF background noise spectrum looks like?

Tags: antenna, frequency, spectrum-analyzer, vlf, ulf

In the ELF-VLF frequency band,some background noise like Schumann resonances shows in the spectrum analyzer as peaks.
[image]

I want to have a overview look of the background noise of ELF-VLF frequency band,but have no spectrum analyzer and antenna which can analyze ELF-VLF signal,and I googled but has no expected result.

How  the ELF-VLF background noise spectrum looks like?

Comment: how would you even observe that spectrum? You literally can't do that without a nation-sized antenna.

Comment: An antenna can either be small, and highly tuned for a narrow bandwidth, or it can be wideband and large. "large" in terms of wavelengths, which I leave up to you to calculate. Now, when you say you want to observe background noise, you'll need an antenna that is wideband AND known and constant in gain. That's a nation-level research institute problem.

Comment: So, while your question is indeed an interesting one, it bears the question of "what is it that you actually need to observe", because no matter what you observe, you'll never *see* that background spectrum.

Comment: (downvote for lack of research, by the way, the wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schumann_resonances#Measurements) on Schumann resonances actually describes the measurement method & effort. )

Comment: @MarcusMüller,searched again and again,there's no one picture to show an overview of `natural background spectrum`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a spectrum analyzer for such low frequencies, more like a very accurate voltmeter that you can record over long periods.
As the antenna, you will need something huge, I recommend the power grid. Filter everything out above 59 Hz and see what you are left with. Might have to do some different filtering to try and find Schumann resonances. Make it portable, so when you want to change the antenna layout go to a friends house and plug it in there :)